# Vector length attribute not the same after convert to raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, rasterization

In QGIS I've successfully used GRASS `v.to.rast` to convert a SHP file to a raster and then raster>conversion>BMP. My output looks great.

The raster info says it is w = 3070, h = 8727. Unit is meters. However, when I looked at the vector attributes table, it says the length is 3435629 m. How can I make sure my raster is capturing the appropriate length? I don't understand how 3435629 is coming out as 8727 in the raster.

Comment: What is the projection and nature of the vector? Is it a single line, a multi-point line or a polygon? Or multiple polygons/lines?

Comment: Hi, it is a polygon. It was originally in  NAD 83 / Conus Albers but I changed it to WGS 84 / UTM zone 10. I need the output to be in UTM. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "length". I understand that property for a line, but not for a polygon. It could be "maximum width" or it could be "perimeter distance". In any case if it is in the attribute table it must be a calculated value and was presumably calculated in the original CRS. Hence, could be somewhat different if re-calculated after projection change.

Comment: It is a multipolygon, sorry I am new at QGIS. I didn't force this calculation, I just saw it in the attributes table. How does one recalculate length after the projection change? Or rather, is it possible to make sure the length, or area, is preserved when going back and forth between different CRS? I need the map in UTM for a different software, then will run a program on it, and put it back into QGIS into its original CRS. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm still uncertain what is meant by "length" with a multipolygon so you need to establish this first. It is possible to calculate attributes "on the fly" using an expression and virtual fields. I suggest you first search for similar questions and consult this link: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html. It is not the current qgis version but will give you some guidance. If you are still struggling then ask another question specifically about updating virtual fields to store the required info. One of the gurus will be able to help.Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the info!